# Add zipping capability to existing StreamWriter code

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-4.0, io, zip

The program I am working on is currently using a `StreamWriter` to create one or many text files in a target folder. Off `StreamWriter` class, I am using `WriteLine` and its `IDisposable` interface via `Using` directive (for implicit `.Close`).

I need to add an option to create one or many text files *in a zip archive* inside a target folder. I was going to change existing code to use streams, so it's possible to use a ZIP file as an output (planning to use [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/)).

I was thinking to create some `GetOutputStream` function and feed that into the currently existing method. This function would determine whether *archive* option is set, and either create plain files, or archive them. Problem is that `MemoryStream`, which looks like a good buffer class to use with `DotNetZip`, does not intersect with `StreamWriter` in the inheritance hierarchy.

Looks like my only option is to create some `IWriteLine` interface, which would implement `WriteLine` and `IDisposable`. Then branch two new child classes from `StreamWriter` and `MemoryStream`, and implement `IWriteLine` in them.

Is there a better solution?

The current code conceptually looks like this:

```vb
Using sw As StreamWriter = File.CreateText(fullPath)
  sw.WriteLine(header)
  sw.WriteLine(signature)
  While dr.Read 'dr=DataReader
    Dim record As String = GetDataRecord(dr)
    sw.WriteLine(record)
  End While
End Using
```

For code samples, either **VB.NET** or **C#** is fine, although this is more of a conceptual question.

**EDIT:** Cannot use .NET 4.5's `System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive`, have to stick with .NET 4.0. We still need to support clients running on Windows 2003.

Comment: I'm not following why `StreamWriter` and `MemoryStream` would need a common ancestry.

Comment: @KeithPayne: To be able to return either through a common ancestor type. Similar to handling regular and masked textboxes with textboxbase class.

Comment: Is there a reason in the context of what you are trying to accomplish? I ask only because these two types, `StreamWriter` and `MemoryStream`, have nothing in common of themselves. The only reason why they would be associated with one another is that a `StreamWriter` can write bytes to a `MemoryStream` (or a `FileStream` for that matter).

Comment: @KeithPayne: Existing code works with a StreamWriter. I was hoping to use it without changes by passing a stream from a zip file. But it seems to be not possible with DotNetZip. My problem is getting a writable stream (but without memory overhead) and then wrapping it via Using clause, same as it works now, and have that Using clause close the stream & close the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the StreamWriter(Stream) constructor to have it write to a MemoryStream.  Set the Position back to 0 so you can then save the written text to the archive with ZipFile.Save(Stream).  Check the ZipIntoMemory helper method in the project's [sample code](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=VB-Examples&referringTitle=Examples) for guidance.

Comment: Will it hold the whole file contents in memory until `ZipFile.Save(Stream)`? The files can be rather big in size.

Comment: That's the job of the garbage collector, not of ZipFile.  "Rather big" is of course a good reason to actually use a file instead of a MemoryStream.

Comment: I could not find an option in Ionic zip to add a file to archive, without having this file on disk or totally sitting in memory. Ideally, yes, it should start adding the contents to archive as soon as it's available, so only the current line is kept in memory. Did I miss this option?

Comment: Yes, file on disk.  There is no third option.  There's no reason at all to avoid it, the file content gets buffered in RAM by the file system cache anyway.  This runs at memory speeds as long as the machine has enough RAM.

Comment: What if the file is 1GB in size? Yes, most modern computers have much more than that. However, when running on a virtual machine, memory consumption is a concern. Is this limitation because zipping algorithm does not support streaming in its full extent, or just an oversight of Ionic zip?

Comment: If you ever figure out how to *insert* bytes into a file then you'll know how to make a zip utility work better.  Not that you'd bother, you'll have a Lear Jet and unfettered access to Cuban cigars and dancing girls that make you die young but with a smile on your face.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, with .NET 4.5 System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive class (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) you no longer need DotNetZip at least for common zipping tasks.

It could look like this:

```
        string filePath = "...";

        //Create file.
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Create(filePath))
        {
            //Create archive infrastructure.
            using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(fileStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                SqlDataReader sqlReader = null;

                //Reading each row into a separate text file in the archive.
                while(sqlReader.Read())
                {
                    string record = sqlReader.GetString(0);

                    //Archive entry is a file inside archive.
                    ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.CreateEntry("...", CompressionLevel.Optimal);

                    //Get stream to write the archive item body.
                    using (Stream entryStream = entry.Open())
                    {
                        //All you need here is to write data into archive item stream.
                        byte[] recordData = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(record);
                        MemoryStream recordStream = new MemoryStream(recordData);
                        recordStream.CopyTo(entryStream);

                        //Flush the archive item to avoid data loss on dispose.
                        entryStream.Flush();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot use .NET 4.5. I will add this info to the question.